# Added items to JPanel dont' show up

Tags: java, swing

I was hoping anyone could help me with this. I can't really find anyone describing this exact issue. In my main class (`Window`) that extends `JFrame` I add an object of a class (`Panel`) that extends `JPanel` and add it to my frame.

So far so good, everything in the `JPanel` class shows up as they should, but when I in my main class create `ShapeDef` object (used to define and draw figures), and then try to add it to the `Panel`, the figures won't show up. Why? I tried using `revalidate()` and `repaint`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's some of the code:

Main-class:

```
public class Window extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

private JPanel myPanel;
private ShapeDef rect1, rect2;

public Window(){
    super("Test Window");
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    myPanel = new Panel(new BorderLayout()); 
    myPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    rect1 = new ShapeDef("Rectangle", Color.green, 200, 300, 20, 80);
    rect2 = new ShapeDef("Rectangle", Color.BLUE, 300, 700, 50, 40);
    myPanel.add(rect1);
    myPanel.add(rect2);

    add(myPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame myFrame = new PongInvaders();
            myFrame.setSize(1280, 720);
            myFrame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            myFrame.pack();
            myFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

ShapeDef class:

```
public class ShapeDef extends JComponent{
    private final Color color;
    private final int x, y, width, height;
    private final String type;

    public ShapeDef(String type, Color color, int x, int y, int width, int height){
        this.type = type;
        this.color = color;
        setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

    }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("Rectangle")){
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        }
        else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("Oval")){
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
        }
    }
}
```

The current version of the code suggested by Keqiang Li draws both of the rectangles, but rect2 spawns at (0,0) while rect1 spawns at the correct coordinates. So basically the question is answered, so thank you all for your help. However why is it that only one of the rectangles spawn at (0,0) while the other spawns at set coordinates, when they're both added to the same JPanel?

@MadProgrammer Although your answer was not the one I expected, I think it's the one I needed. You definitely live up to your user name. Thank you so much for taking the time to teach me a little more about creating a better code structure.

I would also like to point out that the other answers were very helpful and enlightening, and that they also taught me alot.

Comment: Why `Panel` class has a Constructor method named `RandomShape`? and also, you really want to draw things for JPanel by overriding its `paintComponent` method? It looks better to me if you just add labels or other components in a `JPanel`

Comment: The other thing is, it's really not good practice to name your customized class the same as Java library class, such as `Panel`, 'Window`, add your own prefix.

Comment: He's drawing filled shapes in the paintComponent method.

Comment: @FredK not in `Panel` class

Comment: @Keqiang - I missed that. And you're right, there doesn't seem to be any reason to create a subclass of JPanel here.

Comment: Don't call `setBackground` in `paintComponent`

Comment: IMHO I don't think your approach is a good one, i wouldn't be using a `JComponent` in this way, instead, I'd be defining a `Drawable` class which defines the properties the basic properties common to all the shapes, then make subclasses of these to represent each shape, these I would add to a `DrawablePanel` of some kind which would maintain a `List` of them and simply paint them itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I think you're approaching the solution from the wrong angle.  Components aren't really designed to do this, sure you can make them do it, but it leads down some interesting paths which could have you bleeding in the gutter if you're not careful.

Instead, I'd define a "basic" shape which can be "painted" and from, define all you other shapes.

```
public interface Drawable {
    public Color getStrokeColor();
    public Color getFillColor();
    public Rectangle getBounds();
    public void paint(Graphics2D g2d);
}

public abstract class AbstractDrawable implements Drawable {

    private Color strokeColor;
    private Color fillColor;

    public AbstractDrawable(Color strokeColor, Color fillColor) {
        this.strokeColor = strokeColor;
        this.fillColor = fillColor;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getStrokeColor() {
        return strokeColor;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getFillColor() {
        return fillColor;
    }

}

public class RectangleDrawable extends AbstractDrawable {

    private Rectangle bounds;

    public RectangleDrawable(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color strokeColor, Color fillColor) {
        super(strokeColor, fillColor);
        bounds = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return bounds;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.setColor(getFillColor());
        g2d.fill(getBounds());
        g2d.setColor(getStrokeColor());
        g2d.draw(getBounds());
    }

}

public class OvalDrawable extends AbstractDrawable {

    private Ellipse2D bounds;

    public OvalDrawable(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color strokeColor, Color fillColor) {
        super(strokeColor, fillColor);
        bounds = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return bounds.getBounds();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics2D g2d) {
        g2d.setColor(getFillColor());
        g2d.fill(bounds);
        g2d.setColor(getStrokeColor());
        g2d.draw(bounds);
    }

}
```

I'd then have a dedicated component which was capable of managing and painting them

[image: Simple Shapes]

```
public class DrawablePane extends JPanel {

    private List<Drawable> drawables;

    public DrawablePane() {
        drawables = new ArrayList<>(25);
    }

    public void add(Drawable drawable) {
        drawables.add(drawable);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        for (Drawable drawable : drawables) {
            drawable.paint(g2d);
        }
        g2d.dispose();
    }

}
```

Which might be used something like...

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        DrawablePane pane = new DrawablePane();
        pane.add(new RectangleDrawable(10, 10, 100, 150, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN));
        pane.add(new OvalDrawable(100, 20, 50, 50, Color.MAGENTA, Color.BLUE));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(pane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can any one explain the down vote? Does the answer not answer the users question? Does it do something wrong? I'd be interested in learning how it might be improved

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest problem is that you are overriding all of the dimensions (x,y,width,height) in ShapeDef rather than using the JCompoment methods (setSize, setPreferredSize(), setLocation) to set them. Thus your ShapeDefs have no size and any painting you do in them will be blocked by the graphics clipping.

You also should explicitly set the layout manager of your `Panel` to null

Comment: And there is no reason to call pan.revalidate() and pan.repaint() in the Window constructor. Should call pack() before setVisible(true).

Comment: I have an itchy finger to give you a -1 for the `null` layout suggestion

Comment: @MadProgrammer I know where your coming from. If this was for a business solution, I wouldn't recommend null layout. But given the code OP posted / already developed, going through how to override getPreferredSize or use setPreferredSize seems/ed overly complicated

Comment: @ControlAltDel There is an alternative which doesn't use components as the shape renderer

Answer (score 1):

> Added items to JPanel dont' show up

If you extends to `JComponent`, `JComponent` itself already has properties governing its dimension and location such as `x`, `y`, `width`, `height`.

However, instead of using the inherited properties, you are creating another set of properties with the same names which could be shadowing the inherited attributes.

I see that you are creating your own `x`, `y`, `width`, `height` which is not necessary. If those are created for other purposes, you may want to rename them to something else.

---

Other than that, if you just want to have some custom drawing, you don't always have to extends your `ShapeDef` class to a `JComponent`. You can do this:

```
class ShapeDef
{
    //other constructors and attributes not shown
    public void draw(Graphics g){
        //draw your drawings here..
    }
}
```

Let your JPanel hold an instance of ShapeDef, and to draw it in the JPanel, just do it as:

```
public MyPanel extends JPanel
{
    ShapeDef shapeDef;

    //initializations and constructors not shown

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        shapeDef.draw(g);        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what ControlAltDel said in [his Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36875371/6258375) (setting LayoutManager to null) you have to set the x and y coordinates to zero for fillRect and fillOval. If you do not do this, the rectangle won't be visible because of clipping.

```
public class ShapeDef extends JComponent {
    private final Color color;
    private int width, height;
    private final String type;

    public ShapeDef(String type, Color color, int x, int y, int width, int height){
        this.type = type;
        this.color = color;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.setBounds(x, y, width, height); // creates a bounding box for your drawing
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("Rectangle")){
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height); // draws inside of your bounding box
            System.out.println("Rect");
        }
        else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("Oval")){
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillOval(0, 0, width, height); // draws inside of your bounding box
        }
    }
}
```

Also please consider using an enum instead Strings for the type parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ShapeDef` class should have its size and location determined. You could define it as following:

```
public class ShapeDef extends JComponent {
    private final Color color;
    private final String type;

    public ShapeDef(String type, Color color, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.type = type;
        this.color = color;

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        setLocation(new Point(x, y));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Rectangle")) {
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillRect(getX(), getY(), getSize().width, getSize().height);
            System.out.println("Rect");
        } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("Oval")) {
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillOval(getX(), getY(), getSize().width, getSize().height);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in your window class like this:

```
public class MyWindow extends JFrame {
    private JPanel myPanel;
    private ShapeDef shape;

    public MyWindow() {
        super("Test Window");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        myPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        myPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        shape = new ShapeDef("Rectangle", Color.green, 200, 300, 20, 80);
        myPanel.add(shape, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(myPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame myFrame = new MyWindow();
                myFrame.pack();
                myFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You really don't need that customized `Panel` class regarding what you are doing with it.

Comment: I tried your version (ignoring the panel class) but problem here is that the rectangle scales with the window, so instead of being its set size it's always the same size as the window

Comment: @Name55555555 I thought that's what your original code tried to do because you wanna the  shape to be a component. If your code had worked, it would have worked the way like this too.  To achieve your requirement, you need to add your shape in a panel with the same size, and add this panel to your frame while your frame not using a BorderLayout, FlowLayout will keep the panel's size. Or, what you can do, is to use a GridBagLayout to layout your components.