# Java Graphics Only Paint on Button Click

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I'm not sure how java graphics work. It seems
to be executing something itself so I am trying to break it
down.

I'm trying to create the blank JPanel and then only draw to it
once the JButton has been clicked but it doesn't work

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class testGui {

   // global ======================================================================

   static gui      gc_gui;

   // main ========================================================================

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      gc_gui = new gui();
      gc_gui.cv_frame.setVisible(true);
      listeners();
   }

   // action listeners ============================================================

   public static void listeners() {

      ActionListener ll_square = new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            gc_gui.cv_content.draw(graphic);
         }
      };

      gc_gui.cv_button.addActionListener(ll_square);

   }

   // gui =========================================================================

   public static class gui {

      JFrame    cv_frame;
      JButton   cv_button;
      content   cv_content;

      public gui() {

         cv_frame = new JFrame();
         cv_frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         cv_frame.setTitle("Test GUI");
         cv_frame.setSize(600, 400);
         cv_frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());   

         cv_button = new JButton("Square");

         cv_content = new content();
         cv_content.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
         cv_content.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));

         cv_frame.add(cv_button);
         cv_frame.add(cv_content);

      }

   }

   // content =====================================================================

   public static class content extends JPanel {

      public void paint(Graphics graphic) {
         super.paint(graphic);
      }

      public void update() {
         super.repaint();
      }

      public void draw(Graphics graphic) {
         Graphics2D graphic2D = (Graphics2D) graphic;
         graphic2D.setPaint(Color.RED);
         graphic2D.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
      }

   }

}
```

I create the content JPanel without the draw function being
called and then I try to call it using my ActionListener
although it is crashing because of the graphic variable.

What is the correct way to use the java graphics utility?

*UPDATE*

Maybe I'm not asking this question right but it is possible to
create a blank image.

Then draw additional images to that images (squares) after a button
has been clicked?

not just updating the dimensions using global variables but generating
new images to that existing image

Comment: *"I'm not sure how java graphics work"* - Then maybe you should start by having a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how it does work

Comment: Using graphics in java has been the most agonizing thing I've ever done in java. I've tried to use the documentation but it seems very niche to the requirements in the specific examples.

Comment: Not really, Swing's painting process is well documented, you just need to change your design (and way of thinking) to work with it

Comment: I can't find anything for creating new graphics dynamically though

Comment: Why do you need to?  Swing will give you the `Graphics` context that it is using to paint the components when it triggers a paint cycle

Comment: draw the red square once the button has been clicked. if it's clicked again, then draw another square etc.

Comment: You don't need to create a new `Graphics` context to do that, you need to define a model which states what you want to paint and override the `paintComponent` method of your `JPanel` and then paint the state of the model, as a [conceptual example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36875192/added-items-to-jpanel-dont-show-up/36887364#36887364) (don't forget to call `repaint` when the model is updated)

Comment: Is there a way to stop the paint function from being called automatically?

Comment: No, not using Swing, Swing uses the `RepaintManager` (and system event queue) to schedule repaints as required (passive rendering), if you want control over the paint process you'll need to use a [`BufferStrategy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) (and [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html)), but that precludes the use of Swing components, as it's using a different painting model then the one Swing uses

Comment: Of course, you could use a `BufferedImage` as a canvas and call `createGraphics()` when the button is clicked. Draw to the graphics object, **dispose of it** then call `repaint()` on the component displaying the image (I typically just show it in a label) to see the GUI update. But keeping a model as described by @MadProgrammer is the more versatile/powerful way to do it, in that e.g. later it is easy to remove any object added to the collection, then repaint without it.

Comment: I really doubt I will be able to get the model working if I can barely get the first attempt working :'D

Answer (score 1):

> but it is possible to create a blank image. Then draw additional images to that images (squares) after a button has been clicked?

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for two common ways to do painting.

The example allows you to draws Rectangles with the mouse. In your case the logic will be simpler as you would just invoke the `addRectangle(...)` method when you click a button. Of course you need to set the size/location of the Rectangle somehow.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class TestGui {

public static Content content;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle("Test GUI");
    frame.setSize(429, 385);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JButton cv_button = new JButton("Square");
    cv_button.setBounds(10, 159, 70, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(cv_button);
    cv_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Content.isToDraw = true;
            content.paintImmediately(content.getBounds());
            Content.isToDraw = false;

        }
    });

    JButton cv_buttonClear = new JButton("Clear");
    cv_buttonClear.setBounds(10, 179, 70, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(cv_buttonClear);
    cv_buttonClear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            content.paintImmediately(content.getBounds());

        }
     });

    content = new Content();
     content.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
    content.setBounds(87, 11, 287, 312);
    frame.getContentPane().add(content);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}

 class Content extends JPanel {

public static Boolean isToDraw = false;

public void paintComponent(Graphics arg0) {
    if (isToDraw) {
        arg0.setColor(Color.RED);
        arg0.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    } else {
        super.paintComponent(arg0);
    }
}
}
```